# How to Sorting in ascending and descending order Angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to sort data from my method in ascending and descending order.
this is my method.

```js
public get students(): Student[] {
    return this._dashboardService.account.students;
}
```

This is my component.html code

```html
<li *ngFor="let stud of students">
    <div class="{{stud == selectedStudent && highlightStudent ? 'hoveffect' : ''}}">
        <div class="hovlink">
            <a (click)="setStudent(stud)">
                <img [src]="stud.imageUrl ? getStudentFaceImage(stud.imageUrl) : tempDpImage" />
                <!--<span>{{stud.firstName}}</span>-->
            </a>
        </div>
        <h4>{{stud.schoolId}}</h4>              
    </div>
</li>
```

Kindly help me if you know a solution to it.

this is student class.

```
export class Student {
  public userID: number;
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;
  public schoolId: number;
  public schoolName: string;
  public classId: number;
  public className: string;
  public sectionId: number;
  public sectionName: string;
  public currencyCode: string;
  public favImageWithoutCorselCount: number;
  public NonfavImageWithoutCorselCount: number;
  public photos: listData<any>;
  public products: listData<any>;
  public packages: listData<any>;
  public orders: any;
  public downloads: listData<any>;
  public offers: listData<any>;
  public cart: any;
  public supportDetail: SupportDetail;
  public timeStamp: any;
  public isSibling: number;
  public EventName: string;
  public QrCode: string;
}
```

Comment: could you please provide schema for student class. On what  field basis you want to do order?

Comment: thank you for reply i have edited my question pls check